# Create audio call app in react native with webrtc

Tags: node.js, react-native, webrtc, peerjs

I want to create a simple audio call app in react native (webrtc) with backend stuff (in nodejs), can anyone suggest me a good resource?

Wanted to create a prototype for audio call in react native webrtc with node js

Comment: Socket.io would be good choice to start with

Comment: Actually, I have only a little bit of knowledge about webrtc and socket.io, so can you please share any link from where I can learn all the things? and can make simple audio call functionality with nodejs

Comment: i found this article explaining the same you could try it [Building a Video Chat App with Node.js + Socket.io + WebRTC](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/building-a-video-chat-app-with-node-js-socket-io-webrtc-26f46b213017)